# Error when executing query

Tags: google-bigquery

What is wrong in my below query. I'm getting this  error "Bad number of arguments. 
 
Expected 3 arguments" I think I am going wrong in SUM statement

```
SELECT  
  groupname,  
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(prodname) AS COUNT_prodname, 
  SUM(IF(category = 'AAA') AND (Label = 'n')) AS COUNT_prod_success  
FROM  
 [mytable]  
WHERE  
  name CONTAINS('XYZ')  
  AND Package ='ABCD'  
  AND (StartTime > ('2016-01-24 00:00:00 UTC')  
    AND StartTime < ('2016-03-16 00:00:00 UTC')  
    OR (StartTime > ('2016-03-26 00:00:00 UTC')  
      AND StartTime < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))  
GROUP BY  
  1  
ORDER BY  
  2 DESC IGNORE CASE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problem with IF() function here

IF(category = 'AAA')

IF function requires three arguments -

```
IF(condition, true_return, false_return)
```

So it should be something like

```
IF(category = 'AAA', 1, 0)
```

In addition - what looks suspicious here (but sure can be by design) is below (extra condition outside IF)

```
AND (Label = 'n')
```

It is well possible that you meant something like

```
IF(category = 'AAA' AND Label = 'n', 1, 0)
```

Comment: Can I not combine two conditions? Is there an alternative to achieve the same goal? Appreciate your help

Comment: clarify  - what you mean by not combine? give an example

Comment: I think this will work... SUM(IF(category = 'AAA',1,0) AND IF(Label ='n',1,0)) AS COUNT_prod_success

Comment: oh i got an error when i included above statement saying "Error: Argument type mismatch in function LOGICAL_AND: first argument is type int32, second argument is type int32"

Comment: the reason for using IF statement is I want to get a count of all records that have category as 'AAA' and label as 'n' but I cant apply this in where clause because my first and second fileds - groupname and prodname count should not have filters of category 'AAA' and label 'n'

Comment: your question was - `What is wrong in my below query.` you got it answered  - clearly! if you have new question - please post new one :o) and don't forget to vote and accept this answer if you feel  it answered your initial question and helped you to progress iwth your task

Comment: Agree, it helped me.. I will post another question

Comment: I can post questions only every 90 minutes :(

Comment: oh, I didn't know about this limitation. is it because of reputation limit or something else? In any case - answering more than one question within the same question is a nightmare, so still post new one when time allows